# Java app gets slower and slower until a full GC is performed

Tags: java, performance, grails, garbage-collection, jvm

I have a program which receives UDP packets, parses some data from them, and saves it to a DB, in multiple threads. It uses Hibernate and Spring via Grails (GORM stand-alone).

It works OK in one server, it starts fast (20-30 ms per packet -except for the very first ones as JIT kicks in-) and after a while stabilizes at 50-60 ms.

However, in a newer, more powerful server it starts fast but gradually gets slower and slower (it reaches 200 ms or even 300 ms per packet, always with the same load). And then, when the JVM performs a full GC (or I do it manually from Visual VM), it gets fast again and the cycle starts over.

Any ideas about what could cause this behaviour? It seems to be getting slower as the Old Gen fills up. Eden fills up quite fast, but GCs pauses seem to be short. And it works OK in the old server, so it's puzzling me.

#### Servers and settings:

The servers specs are:

- Old server: Intel Xeon E3-1245 V2 @ 3.40GHz, 32 GB RAM without ECC
- New server: Intel Xeon E5-1620 @ 3.60GHz, 64 GB RAM with ECC
- OS: Debian 7.6
- JVM:

  - java version "1.7.0_65"
  - Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_65-b17)
  - Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
- JVM settings:

  - Old server: was running with no special RAM or GC params, PrintFlagsFinal gives: -XX:InitialHeapSize=525445120 -XX:+ManagementServer -XX:MaxHeapSize=8407121920 -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseParallelGC
  - New server: tried forcing those same flags, same results.
  - Old server seemed to support UseFastStosb, it was enabled by default. Forcing it in the new server results in a message that says it's not supported.

Comment: Try removing ALL -XX flags.   You should only enable those if you really know what you are doing.

Comment: In the old server no flags were enabled other than -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal and -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags. In the new server, we started using it with no flags, then tried forcing the settings the old server used (heap size and ratios) by chcking what PrintFlagsFinal displayed in the old server.

Comment: Well, what does Visual VM tell you?  Most interesting is garbage collection statistics

Comment: Like I said, Eden fills up quite fast, Old Gen fills very slowly, and GCs pauses seem to be short: 

http://imgur.com/xw9zQJS 

http://imgur.com/SOU3Oyf

Comment: So you have a LOT of short lived objects.  Would any of these objects happen to hold on to a resource that others need to be able to respond?

Comment: Have you checked the Database?, now that your server for Java is faster, have you made sure that the Database can keep up?... remember, making the java layer faster and keeping the same speed on the database could cause a bottleneck as the DB can become saturated with the higher rate of requests... Another thing I would check is contention, usually on multithreaded applications, changing hardware will lead to bigger contention created in the application design due to the improve in processing speed.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to use G1 which is supported by your JVM version?

Applications running with either the CMS or the Parallel Old GC garbage collector would benefit switching to G1 if the application has one or more of the following traits.

(1) Full GC durations are too long or too frequent.
(2) The rate of object allocation rate or promotion varies significantly.
(3) Undesired long garbage collection or compaction pauses (longer than 0.5 to 1 second)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot possibly say if there's anything wrong with your application / the server VM defaults.

Try adding -XX:+PrintGCDetails to know more about young and old generation sizes at the time of garbage collection. According the values, ur initial heap size starts around 525MB and maximum heap is around 8.4GB. The JVM will resize the heap based on the requirement and everytime it resizes this heap, all the young and old generations are resized accordingly which will cause a Full GC.

Also your flags indicate UseParallelGC which will do the young generation collection using multiple threads but old gen is still serially collected using single thread.

The default value of NewRatio is 2 which means that Young gen takes 1/3 of the heap and old gen takes 2/3 of the heap. If you have too many short living objects try resizing young gen size and probably give G1 GC a try now that u're using 7u65.

But before tuning I strongly recommend you to 
(1) Do proper analysis taking GC logs - see if there are any Full GCs during your slow response times
(2) Try Java Mission Control. Use it to monitor your remote server process. Its feature rich and u'll know more information about GC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use -XX:+PrintGCDetails option to see how frequency each GC occurs.

However, I don't think it is GC issue(or GC papameters). As what is said in your post, the program runs OK but problem occurs when it is moved to a new fast machines. My guess is that there is some bottleneck in your program, which in turn slows release references to allocated objects. Consequently, the memory accumlates and VM use a lot of time for GC and memory allocation.

In other means, the procedure who allocates heap memory for package process, and the consumer recycle this memory after packages memory are saved to DB. But the consumer can not catch up procedure speed.

So my suggestion is to check your program and doing some measurements